# How to catch PropertyChanged event, for an object instance that is bound to the SelectedItem of a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to learn WPF with C# so bear with me if the question is naive.

1. I have a class named Person with 2 properties (FirstName, LastName) and 1 computed property (FullName) that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
2. I have an ObservableCollection of type Person, which I have bound to a ListBox.
3. I have an instance of Person, called SelectedPerson, which I have bound to the ListBox SelectedItem property.
4. I have two TextBoxes, which are bound to the SelectedPerson.FullName and SelectedPerson.LastName properties.

So far, everything works as it should:

- Clicking(selecting) a person from the ListBox updates the SelectedPerson instance, and this in turn populates the TextBoxes with the correct information
- Changing either TextBox content updates the SelectedPerson instance, and this in turn updates the contents of the ListBox (when the edited TextBox loses focus)

What I want to achieve now is to somehow listen for the PropertyChanged event of SelectedPerson, so after changing the contents of a TextBox I can run some code. I want the code to run once, after the bound property is changed (like how the ListBox gets updated after editing has stopped), so I don't really want to listen to TextBox's TextChanged event.

Can I use the PropertyChanged event of SelectedPerson, so no matter which Person is the current SelectedItem I can listen for the PropertyChanged event, or do I have to use the PropertyChanged event for each instance of Person in the ObservableCollection? (or... something different?)

For reference, here are relevant excerpts of code for all the above

Person Class

```
  public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       ...
       public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; OnPropertyChanged("FirstName"); OnPropertyChanged("FullName"); }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; OnPropertyChanged("LastName"); OnPropertyChanged("FullName"); }
        }

        public string FullName { get { return $"{LastName} {FirstName}"; } }
    }
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

        private Person _selectedPerson;
        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return _selectedPerson; }
            set { _selectedPerson = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPerson"));  }
        }

        public MainWindow() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            People = new ObservableCollection<Person>
            {
                new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
                new Person { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smith" }
            };
        }
    }
```

And the XAML items

```
...
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" Margin="10"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="First Name" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120" Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Last Name" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120" Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When a `TextBox` is changed, its bound property setter is run.  i.e., FirstName.set or LastName.set is run.  You know this of course.  You can also run your extra code from the setter which would only run when a `TextBox` is changed.  To prevent running your code more than once, check the new value against the backing field value and, if they match, do return.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the PropertyChanged event of SelectedPerson, so no matter which Person is the current SelectedItem I can listen for the PropertyChanged event

Yes. But you need to add code to *also* subscribe ("listen") to the `PropertyChanged` event of your `MainWindow`, so that you can respond to changes in the `SelectedPerson` property value. That is, when that property value changes, you need to unsubscribe from the previously-set `Person` object's `PropertyChanged` event, and subscribe to the event on the now-set `Person` object.

You are on the right track preferring to do this at the view model level instead of with the view itself (e.g. `TextBox`). The more you keep all your non-UI logic together in the view model the better.

Note that this actually means you'd also be better off to have a "main" view model, which holds the list of `Person` objects and currently selected item, rather than having your window implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Also, for what it's worth, I have found it works better (for me, anyway) to implement a base class that view model objects inherit, which has a helper method to update backing fields, raising `PropertyChanged` as necessary, and providing a optional callback to allow responding to property changes, rather than having to actually subscribe to the event (at least in cases where you always want to respond…in this particular example, that might not help because you only want to handle the event when the `Person` object is the currently-selected one).